# Can I repair a stone step?

Tags: repair

I have a 1911 property with a stone? back door step which is worn and either crumbled or cracked.

A few years back a plasterer did a repair and think skimmed it, but needs doing again.

I had a Google around and Toupret exterior masonry repair filler had good reviews, as well as U-can repair steps concrete repair from B&Q.

I can do most things and am happy to give this a go.

I think the step needs an angle adding or building up so the water runs away also.

Any advice or thoughts much appreciated.

**Pictures Added**

[image: stepfrominside]

[image: setpoutside]

Here is the step from inside and outside.

Also photos of windowsills, also needing work to help with type of stone.

[image: sill]

Comment: Can you provide a picture?  Be careful with stairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely you can repair it! A photo would be helpful to give us a idea what is needed, etching and adding a new layer or maybe a thin stone veneer to help it look original. I have etch granite steps that were worn over 100 years a thin layer of mortar holding a 1/4 inch granite slab on top of the steps was approved and later awarded for a restoration project on a Vicky, ( one of about a dozen things that were mentioned in the award) but this was decades ago. The same process will still work.

Comment: Thanks for sorting my post Daniel and Graham!

Comment: Can anyone please let me know the best options or what to use to repair this?

Comment: First I would go to a monument place (the ones that do headstones) take the measurements and order a plate to fit the threshold then I would chip out the past repairs . After the surface is cut down to the original or slightly lower level I would put thinset down with a notched trowel lay the new stone threshold and make sure it is positioned correctly, clean up any thinset that may have squished out and let it set up over night . I could the monument place in my town was the best place to get unusual shaped granite in different colors. A counter top place usually has much thicker but possible

Comment: Just about any tile could be used and may be cheaper but tile and stone will outlast plasters and mortar only mixes

Comment: Ok thanks, the thinset on the top and make good around the edges and the inside part? Is the Toupet exterior masonry repair filler a good one?

Comment: I don’t know that brand but if you use a stone or tile top just about any masonry  product should work. I suggest stone as it will last our lifetimes.